# Can I make POST or GET requests from an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way using the iPhone SDK to get the same results as an HTTP POST or GET methods?

Answer (score 44):

Assume your class has a `responseData` instance variable, then:

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

NSURLRequest *request =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And then add the following methods to your class:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Show error
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Once this method is invoked, "responseData" contains the complete result
}
```

This will send a GET. By the time the final method is called, `responseData` will contain the entire HTTP response (convert to string with [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encoding:].

Alternately, for POST, replace the first block of code with:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = @"Some post string";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: I posted a follow up question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431826/making-get-and-post-requests-from-an-iphone-application-clarification-needed  (I figured it was worthy of it's own question.)

Comment: Be sure to check that [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; call for a nil return.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Objective C, you'll need to use the NSURL, NSURLRequest, and NURLConnection classes. [Apple's NSURLRequest doc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/NSURLRequest_Class.pdf). HttpRequest is for JavaScript.