# Read a .txt file from the web - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone app, how can I download a .txt file from the web, and then get it's contents into an NSString. For instance, say the text file was located at http://www.somewebsite.com/textfile.txt

Then what I want to do is:

```
if(user has internet connection)
   NSString *textFile = download text file from http://www.somewebsite.com/textfile.txt
else
  NSLog(@"user has no internet");
```

Can someone show me code to do this?

Comment: Using NSURLRequest you can easily download the file, save this file and use it according to your requirements. You can take help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464252/how-to-download-a-file-by-using-nsurlconnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this library to download files via http: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: that seems to be a bit complicated. I only need to download a txt file. any simpler ideas? that download is way too complex for me. I'm more of a noobie.

Comment: See if anyone else has a suggestion, but that's actually the simplest way I've found to download a file via http on the iPhone, unfortunately.

Comment: To download a file you can simply instantiate a string with `stringWithContentsOfURL:`. You don't need the whole library for this.

Answer (score 1):

To test for internet connectivity, look at Apple's `Reachability` example. It has all the code you'll need for that.

To get the file, you may want to check out this SO post: [Can I make POST or GET requests from an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319463/can-i-make-post-or-get-requests-from-an-iphone-application/322573) and its relevant follow-up post: [Making GET and POST Requests from an iPhone Application - Clarification Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431826/making-get-and-post-requests-from-an-iphone-application-clarification-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Check NSURLConnection classes.