# URLs and POST on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I sanitize URLs made from strings to replace characters like space to %20 and etc?

How can I Print a NSURL in NSLog?

How can I send data to a webserver using POST? i know that for HTML GET:

```
NSURL * theURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
NSString * results = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
```

will do the deal, but what is i am sending over secret data such as username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier framework for running POST requests is Ben Copsey's [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) kit, which wraps around NSHTTPRequest and adds a lot of useful functionality. It will save you time and it is definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

First off, multiple questions should be asked as multiple questions, but I'll answer anyway:

1. `NSString *escapedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
2. `NSLog(@"URL is: %@, contents is: %@", myURLObject, [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURLObject]);`
3. Sending `POST` data has already been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319463/can-i-make-post-or-get-requests-from-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Also, if you aren't releasing theURL later on, it will be leaked.

Answer (score 1):

The questions changed while I was writing my answer..This is answering how to POST.

You will need to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).