# canonical way to read plist from URL into NSDictionary? How to control timeout?

Tags: iphone, timeout, plist, nsdictionary

I have a servlet that serves up a plist XML file.  What's the best way to slup this into an `NSDictionary`?  I have this basically working with:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [ [ NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/blah"] ];
```

But then I have no control over the timeout; I'd rather not have my UI hang for 60 seconds just because the server (which I may not control) is having a hissy fit.  I know about `NSURLRequest`, which will let me do the following:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/blah"
                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
             timeoutInterval:5 ];
```

But I don't quite see how to feed that to NSDictionary.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this using the asynchronous methods. Start with this answer/post:

[Can I make POST or GET requests from an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319463/can-i-make-post-or-get-requests-from-an-iphone-application/322573#322573)

This will get you your data and place it in a varibale: responseData. Now you need to add your code to convert it to a NSDictionary in the following method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

I've found 2 possible ways to convert NSData to NSDictionary. This way is straight from the Apple [Archives and Serializations Guide](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/serializing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000952-97859).

```
NSString *errorStr = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format; 

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData: responseData
                mutabilityOption: NSPropertyListImmutable
                format: &format
                errorDescription: &errorStr];
```

Second:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [string propertyList];
[string release];
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Corey. Came looking for one way... you gave me two.