# Modify a UIWebView request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I want to change all user request to use the POST method (as opposed to GET). If the request is already a POST request then append a new parameter 'userId=2382938' to the post data. If the request is GET then change it to POST and add 'userId=2382938'.

I know I can intercept a UIWebView using this. Not sure where to go from here.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

//add post parameter here
}
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific as to what you would like to do?

Comment: I want to change all user request to use the POST method (as opposed to GET). If the request is already a POST request then append a new parameter 'userId=2382938' to the post data. If the request is GET then change it to POST and add 'userId=2382938'. Thanks

Comment: assuming that u have control over the html inside the webview, you can also do what you want by catching form posts (via onsubmit) inside the html and doing a bit of magic in javascript :)

Comment: I don't have control over the HTML. It's a 3rd party website.

Comment: Look my answer here [Modify URL request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20484616/1460329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How do I insert a POST request into a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002765/how-do-i-insert-a-post-request-into-a-uiwebview):

> You can use an NSMutableURLRequest,
>   set the HTTP method to POST, and then
>   load it into your UIWebView using
>   -loadRequest.

Comment: How do I convert it to a MutableURLRequest?

Comment: @Tim: `[request mutableCopy]`?

Comment: so use the function in my main post, and inside the function (convert request to MutableURLRequest, change to POST, add new parameter, then use loadRequest and return NO)? Is this correct?

Comment: @Tim: That sounds fine. Try it out.

Comment: How do you append data to an existing POST NSUrlRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like that.

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

   NSMutableURLRequest *modifiedRequest = [request mutableCopy];

   modifiedRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:parametrisedURL]; // here you will add your desired parameters

   modifiedRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

   [webview loadRequest:modifiedRequest];

   // Do other stuff if any

   return YES;
}
```