# Instance variables?

Tags: objective-c

[Can I make POST or GET requests from an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319463/can-i-make-post-or-get-requests-from-an-iphone-application#322573)

In this article, the second answer mentions 'Assume your class has a responseData instance variable, then.' What does this mean and how would I add one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class's header file, there will be a section along these lines:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}

// Soem method declarations here
@end
```

Inside, the braces, add a declaration for the instance variable you want:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {

}

// Soem method declarations here
@end
```

I'd recommend reading [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) if this is unfamiliar to you, because there are a lot of aspects of the language that are more subtle than this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Got the book - just was getting a bit confused - cheers!