# Posting a URL iPhone 

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c

I need to submit an HTML form on a website. It uses the post method. How can I post the form with the values of two UITextFields and submit the form using merely code. Then I need to get the response of the post in html. I don't have any code so far and I couldn't find anything on google! Could anybody please help me solve this problem? I need to submit this form without using a UIWebView. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also have a look at ASIHttpRequest.  This uses POST methods as well, and in my opinion much easier to use than NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319463/can-i-make-post-or-get-requests-from-an-iphone-application) from another question, credit to Matt Gallagher from cocoa with love :D